# Appropriate database schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

My database design skills are a little rusty. I've done the best I can but have no way of knowing if what I've produced is good, bad or "good enough".

Could I please have some feedback on my design.

To be more specific: Will this design work sufficiently?

Database will be mySQL.

Thanks.
J.

[image: Schema]

*edit*: Some further clarification:

- A brand may have a category or it may not.
- The meta table can be filled out without it actually belonging to a model (in cases where the actual model is not known)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know your full needs, so I'm assuming the highlighted notes indicate a well thought out design.

I like most of your conventions, but I'd avoid using camel case for column names for foreign keys and use tablename_columname (i.e. user_id, brand_id, etc...)

If all brands have a category, I'd kill the connection from brand to model.  Do all brands have a category?  If no, then you're stuck with both foreign keys.

If all models have at least one meta, you can lose the type foriegn key in the model table.  You then could also drop the brand foriegn key in the model class as well as the country

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A brand may have a category or it may not. The meta table can be filled out without it actually belonging to a model.

Comment: yes it can. The model table will be pre populated with known models. A user will have the option to select a known model, if they know what it is. If not, they can still add other info they do know about.

Comment: @Jarrod  this is pretty flexible architecture.  Could a model have a country and have a meta that had a different country?  If so, there's not much more you can do.  If all model's properties will match a meta it's linked to, I'd get rid of any duplicate properties in meta and model and just put them in meta and always have at least one meta for a model (but not necessarily a model for a meta...)

Comment: Good question! I allowed this as the meta data would "override" the model data. But I think it's more sensible to remove country from the model table. (and I'll do the same for type).

Comment: @Jarrod thx, I'm sure I might question your chosen design/architecture if I knew more of the desired implementation, but outside that, you look like you thought the schema out pretty well.  Just one more polite urging to not use camel case column names--stick with lower case :)  Makes later query writing/maintenance more sane if always lower case

Comment: no, thank you. I really just wanted to know that it's not too crazy of a design! Thanks for your help.